# Capture response using Xpath extractor in Jmeter

Tags: xpath, jmeter

I need to extract uuid from the below XML response using xpath extractor in jmeter. Can anyone help me with the expression>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:awsse="xml.test.com/2010/06/Session_v3" xmlns:sca="www.w3.org/2001/05/addressing"><soap:Header><sca:To>www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</sca:To><sca:From><sca:Address>nodeA1.test.webservices.test.com/1ASIRFCUCPA</sca:Address></sca:From><sca:Action>webservices.test.com/test_Shopping_18.1</sca:Action><sca:MessageID>urn:uuid:ba154abc-636c-33b4-3947-6b50651b3f5b</sca:MessageID><sca:RelatesTo RelationshipType="www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/reply">urn:uuid:55c875fa-bda3-461e-aa06-56c28f11ad38</sca:RelatesTo>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're looking for the `MessageID`:

1. You can use XPath [name()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/name) function to extract the value like `urn:uuid:ba154abc-636c-33b4-3947-6b50651b3f5b`. The relevant expression would be:

   ```
   (//*[name() = 'sca:MessageID'])/text()
   ```

   [image]
2. If you want just this `ba154abc-636c-33b4-3947-6b50651b3f5b` part - go for [substring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/substring) function like:

   ```
   substring((//*[name() = 'sca:MessageID'])/text(),10)
   ```

   [image]

More information:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0/)